# How to type a variable with useRef with TypeScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I use `useRef()` to deal with errors of a phone number from an input. I do it like this:

```
const errorPhoneDiv: MutableRefObject<{}> = useRef("");
```

A bit later in the code, I use `errorPhoneDiv.current.innerText` to set the written phone number, but TS tells me :

> Property 'innerText' does not exist on type '{}'

What type should I pass to `MutableRefObject` to accept the `useRef` object?

Comment: Hi Johan! I pasted an answer; please check it and let me know!

Comment: "*… to set the written phone number*" - you should use react rendering for that, not a ref.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `HTMLInputElement` if it's an `input`, `HTMLDivElement` if it's a `div`, etc. You also need an initial value, which could be `null`, in which case you need a null check before accessing `innerHTML`:

```
const errorPhoneDiv = useRef<HTMLInputElement | null>(null);
console.log(errorPhoneDiv.current?.innerHTML);
```

[image]